# How to upload files from Ansible Tower to Artifactory?

Tags: ansible, artifactory, ansible-tower

I'm getting this error every time, but only on specific files when trying to upload from Ansible Tower to Artifactory.

The files are all created on inventory hosts by `Oracle_Collection_Tool`, then fetched to the Ansible Tower Node before uploading to Artifactory. The files all look normal on the hosts where the collection tool is run, and all are fetched successfully. The `value False (type bool)` warning happens with all files.

It's not a bottleneck at the Artifactory end, as I've tried throttling it, and running it against only one inventory host. The same files fail every time, while others succeed.
The playbook task and the error output are below. All URLs/hostnames/usernames etc. have been anonymised. Can anyone help?

Playbook task:

```yaml
- name: Pushing bz2 file to artifactory
  uri:
    url: "{{ artifactory_url }}/{{ directory_str }}/{{ collection_file.stdout }}"
    user: "{{ artifactory_user }}"
    password: "{{ artifactory_password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    method: PUT
    return_content: yes
    src: "/tmp/Oracle_Collection_Tool/output/{{ collection_file.stdout }}"
    headers:
       Content-Type: application/tar
       Accept: application/json
    status_code: 201
    remote_src: no
```

Error:

```json
    {
    "status": -1,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "warnings": [
        "The value False (type bool) in a string field was converted to u'False' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change."
    ],
    "url": "http://artifactory-host:8081/artifactory/linux-team-generic/Oracle_Audit/Collection-hostname_all.tar.bz2",
    "changed": false,
    "elapsed": 30,
    "content": "",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "directory_mode": null,
            "force": false,
            "remote_src": "False",
            "status_code": [
                "201"
            ],
            "body_format": "raw",
            "owner": null,
            "follow": false,
            "client_key": null,
            "group": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "serole": null,
            "content": null,
            "setype": null,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "return_content": true,
            "method": "PUT",
            "body": null,
            "timeout": 30,
            "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "dest": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "force_basic_auth": true,
            "removes": null,
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "user": "linux_account",
            "regexp": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "src": "/home/tower-username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-9999999999.99-999999999999999/Collection-hostname_all.tar.bz2",
            "url": "http://artifactory-host:8081/artifactory/linux-team-generic/Oracle_Audit/Collection-hostname_all.tar.bz2",
            "backup": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "creates": null,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Length": 12408,
                "Content-Type": "application/tar",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            "delimiter": null,
            "mode": null,
            "url_username": "linux_account",
            "attributes": null,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "redirected": false,
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [201]: Request failed: <urlopen error timed out>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Ansible Tower doesn't actually fetch the files to itself, but just copies them to a temporary directory on the Remote Server (I didn't see that in any documentation), so when uploading to Artifactory, it was trying to do it from the Remote Host, therefore I need more firewall rules.