# Troubleshooting fetch_module executed from Ansible Tower (awx)

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm trying to do a very simple fetch file from remote host. Somehow I've never gotten this to work.

Fetching from a remote Linux box to the Ansible Tower (awx) host which is also a Linux box.

Here's the Ansible code:

```
---
- name: get new private key for user
  hosts: tag_Name_ansible_kali
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  
 - name: fetch file
    fetch:
       src: /tmp/key
       dest: /tmp/received/
       flat: yes
```

Here's the result which makes it appear like the fetch worked:

```
{
    "changed": true,
    "md5sum": "42abaa3160ba875051f2cb20be0233ba",
    "dest": "/tmp/received/key",
    "remote_md5sum": null,
    "checksum": "9416f6f64b94c331cab569035fb6bb825053bc15",
    "remote_checksum": "9416f6f64b94c331cab569035fb6bb825053bc15",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

However, going to the `/tmp/received` directory and `ls -lah` shows...

```
[root@ansibleserver received]# ls -lah
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x.  2 awx  awx     6 Mar 12 15:48 .
drwxrwxrwt. 10 root root 4.0K Mar 12 15:49 ..
```

I've tested and if I choose a target `src` file that doesn't exist it won't work, so it's clearly connecting to the remote host. The problem is no matter where I point `dest` on the Ansible server the file doesn't actually write there. Not even sure how it can have a checksum of a file that doesn't exist. I've searched the entire drive and that file does not exist. Is there another log somewhere I can look at where it's actually writing the file? It's not on the remote host either.

Any advice would be appreciated. Seriously scratching my head here.

Comment: I am not familiar with tower, but what if you set a destination somewhere other than `/tmp`? Or what if you run `find /tmp -name key`? There is an option for starting a service with systemd that gives the service a unique /tmp directory, so while the process may put something in what it thinks is `/tmp` it won't be the same `/tmp` that you're looking at. Not suggesting this is the problem, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

On a RHEL 7.9.9 system with Ansible 2.9.25, Python 2.7.5, Ansible Tower 3.7.x the output from an ad-hoc fetch task on CLI for a user on the Tower Server looks like

```
ansible test --user ${USER} --ask-pass --module-name fetch --args "src=/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.txt dest=/tmp/ flat=yes"
SSH password:
test1.example.com | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true,
    "checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83",
    "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
    "md5sum": "d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249",
    "remote_checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83",
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
test2.example.com | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "file not found: /home/user/test.txt"
}
```

and the file was left there. But the command was initiated and executed under user.

The same executed from Ansible Tower as ad-hoc command with arguments `src=/home/user/test.txt dest=/tmp/ flat=yes` reported

```
test2.example.com | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "file not found: /home/user/test.txt"
}
test1.example..com | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83", 
    "dest": "/tmp/test.txt", 
    "md5sum": "d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249", 
    "remote_checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83", 
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
```

And your observation was right, there was no file on the Ansible Tower (`awx`) server. Changing the destination directory to the user reported, if there is an file already

```
}
test1.example.com | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "checksum": null, 
    "dest": "/home/user/test.txt", 
    "file": "/home/user/test.txt", 
    "md5sum": null, 
    "msg": "checksum mismatch", 
    "remote_checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83", 
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
```

that there is an file already. However, it failed also if there was no file.

After changing the destination directory to the user under the Ansible Tower is running (`awx`) via arguments `src=/home/user/test.txt dest=/home/awx/ flat=yes`

```
test1.example.com | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83", 
    "dest": "/home/awx/test.txt", 
    "md5sum": "d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249", 
    "remote_checksum": "4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83", 
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
```

the file was left there correctly

```
ls -al /home/awx/
-rw-r--r--.  1 awx  awx     5 Nov  6 10:42 test.txt
```

Regarding

> The problem is no matter where I point dest on the Ansible server the file doesn't actually write there. ... Any advice would be appreciated. ...

it looks like it is caused by the user context and missing access/write rights and maybe other observations like [*"It turns out that Ansible Tower doesn't actually fetch the files to itself, but just copies them to a temporary directory on the remote server"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66478587/6771046).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
validate_checksum: no
```