# Is there any standard location for persistent files in AWX?

Tags: ansible-awx, ansible-tower

In AWX, is there a standard place where I can save files like the one generated by a task like the following `temp1.txt`?:

```yaml
- name: Create user temp1
  user:
    name: "temp1"
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash    
    password: "{{ lookup('password', 'credentials/temp1.txt encrypt=sha512_crypt length=12') }}"
    createhome: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've did some [troubleshooting of executing from Ansible Tower (awx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607091/).

The Ansible Tower or AWX installation will be usually done under an account and group of `awx`, as well the execution of projects, playbooks, etc.. To be able to save files and store information as requested

> ... is there a standard place where I can save files ...

you will need to do have the rights to write. So it could be possible to place files under `/var/lib/awx/projects` or after creation of a folder with correct rights under

```
ll /home/
drwx------.  2 awx                  awx          4096 Jan 21 12:34 awx
```

This means, you will need to create the structure for storing your files persistent by yourself.

Please take note that one could have a [Clustered Envirionment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/clustering.html) and therefore more than one Tower Node. Which is mainly the reason why there is no "standard place" for storage on the Execution Node. For more information see

**Doucmentation**

- [Instance Groups and Isolated Nodes](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-tower-feature-spotlight-instance-groups-and-isolated-nodes)
- [Execution Environments](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/external_execution_envs.html)
- [Instance Groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/instance_groups.html)