# AWX fetch module directory missing

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I'm working on this environment

```
ansible version = 2.5.1
python version = 2.7.17
awx version = 8.0.0
```

I'm trying to change my ansible project to AWX ( I installed AWX via docker)

I had two hosts called ansible-server and k8s-master

I originally fetched k8s-master's config.yaml to ansibler-server with this playbook
my fetch module worked on ansible playbook on cli (it worked on host : ansible-server)

```
- name: Fetch config.yaml from K8S-Master
  hosts: K8S-Master
  become: yes
  fetch:
    src: /home/vagrant/config.yaml
    dest: /home/vagrant/config.yaml
    flat: true
```

but when I play same playbook on AWX command, it shows me playbook has successed but no file exists on ansible-server

this is my inventory on AWX

```
Inventory : Demo-Inventory
Groups : Ansible-Server, K8S-Master
HOSTS(one each) : 192.168.32.145, 192.167.32.150
```

and I added my host ip on each group

I've fixed settings -> jobs -> job execution path and "extra environment variables" path to

```
/home/vagrant/
and
{
"HOME":"/home/vagrant/"
}
```

I've also checked those directory

```
/var/lib/awx/projects
/home/awx
```

I'm not sure how can I find AWX container's file system
I'll add more informations if I need to.

---

I found out that the file goes to container's directory

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/RANDOMCODE/merged/home/config.yaml
```

how can I get those file (as shell script or as another playbook)

Comment: Does [Troubleshooting fetch_module executed from Ansible Tower (awx)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69863034/6771046) answer our quetion?

Comment: I found out that the fecthed (and copied) file goes to docker's container. but I couldn't figure out how to get those file (as shell script or another task)

Comment: my config.yaml is in that directory

``` /var/lib/docker/overlay2/RANDOM/merged/home/vagrant/config.yaml ```

Comment: Right, as that, the docker container, is the context in which the `awx` is running.

Comment: Can you give me another advice to get those file with playbook or shell script?

Comment: Currently from your question and description for me is not clear from where and which context do you like to access files in [Docker overlay2FS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#how-the-overlay2-driver-works) and what do you try to do with it.

Comment: Thanks. I  AM  trying to get file from dokcer overlay2 but it should be another question which is not related to my original question. Have a nice day