# How can I upload to Artifactory using Ansible from a Windows host?

Tags: curl, ansible, artifactory, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to upload files from my Windows host to my Artifactory repo through Ansible.

To achieve this I am trying to use a CURL command, from local the following works:

```
curl -u <username>:<password> -T C:\path\to\file.txt -k https://artifactory.blokes-server.net/artifactory/Data/
```

In Ansible I have created the following playbook that runs successfully through my template, however no file is actually placed in the Artifactory repo:

```yaml
- name: Artifactory Interactions
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Upload files to Artifactory
      win_command:
        curl -u {{ ct_username }}:{{ ct_password }} -T {{ item.file_path }} -k {{ item.artifactory_path }} --ssl-no-revoke
      with_items: '{{ my_dictionary }}'
```

where `ct_username` and `ct_password` are credentials created in Ansible Tower, and `my_dictionary` is passed in the extra-vars section of Ansible Towers as so:

```yaml
my_dictionary:
  - file_path: C:\path\to\file.txt
    artifactory_path: https://artifactory.blokes-server.net/artifactory/Data/
```

With this implementation my playbook runs successfully but no file is uploaded. However if I omit the `-k` and `--ssl-no-revoke` options in my CURL command I do receive the following error:

```
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - the revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454361/error-uploading-certain-files-from-ansible-tower-to-artifactory) but differs because I am attempting to do this from a Windows host and cannot use the URI function.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `-u <username>:<password>` in `curl`, but "_`ct_username` and `ct_password` are credentials created in Ansible Tower_"? Shouldn't there be not the account from Artifactory since that is a different web service on a different host?

Comment: "_because I am attempting to do this from a Windows host and cannot use the URI function._", but what is preventing you from using [`win_uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_uri_module.html)?

Comment: If you are using `--insecure` in your `curl` command already you can test with `validate_certs: false` in `win_uri` module.

Comment: Hey @U880D, the win_uri module lacks a src parameter so I am not sure if it is possible to do a PUT request with it as there is no substitute I could find in the documentation. As for the variables ct_username and ct_password these are passed to the Windows remote host through Ansible Tower, this is just a secure way to store those credentials; from my local machine I just input the username and password which is why I denote them in <> brackets. Hope this clears up your questions.

Comment: "_Hope this clears up your questions._", actually not. However, can you edit your initial question and add this within the comment given information? Furthermore, I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to upload from the Ansible Control Node as a workaround? And what happens if you just remove `--ssl-no-revoke` and use only `--insecure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [need to add quotes around your variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#when-to-quote-variables-a-yaml-gotcha) calls so that Ansible recognizes them as a variable and not just a part of the string, also since you specify `-k, --insecure` you shouldn't need to specify `--ssl-no-revoke`

```yaml
- name: Artifactory Interactions
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: Upload files to Artifactory
      win_command:
        curl -u "{{ ct_username }}":"{{ ct_password }}" -T "{{ item.file_path }}" -k "{{ item.artifactory_path }}" 
      with_items: '{{ my_dictionary }}'
```

Honestly it's a simple mistake I made when I first started with Ansible as well, seems like you're on the right path to becoming a good DevOps engineer based on the rest of your scripts/configs!